# Does Google PubSub support synchronous pull for its Python API?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-python-api

The documentation I have read has only covered asynchronous pull - I'd like to verify that that is the only option for the Python API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cloud Pub/Sub client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python) only support asynchronous subscribing, which is the recommended way to run a subscriber. For specific use cases where a synchronous pull is needed, use the [REST/HTTP pull method](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull) or the [gRPC pull method](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/5fdd81af96752d7f825d25609d2659e468f1a059/google/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto#L121), which requires [generating the service code](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html).